# jQ, On dropdownlist change/selection, get request on same url with ?somekey=selected-item-value

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

When someone selects a drop down list item, I want to redirect to the same page but with the query string set with

```
www.example.com/?somekey=selected-value
```

where `selected-value` is the numeric value of the option.

I am using jQuery if that makes it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the onchange event in the select element:

```
<select ... onchange="window.location.href='?somekey='+$(this).val();">
```

Or if you want to hook it up using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $('#idOfTheSelect').change(function(){
    window.location.href = '?somekey=' + $(this).val();
  });
});
```

Comment: I'd consider using window.location.replace(), for reasons detailed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery

Comment: If the href already contains a querystring value, this will wipe it out right? hmm...maybe I can check on the server side first.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Heres some code:

```
<select id="redirect">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#redirect").change(function() {
       document.location = "product.html?id=" + $(this).val();
    });
});
```